# Best structure for if statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I was wondering what is the recommended way or the best way for optimization between the two different functions.

The first one (that I would personally choose):

```
def myFunction1(aParameter):
    if aParameter == 0:
        result = 42
    elif aParameter == 1:
        result = 0
    else:
        result = None

    return result
```

The second one:

```
def myFunction2(aParameter):
    if aParameter == 0:
        return 42
    if aParameter == 1:
        return 0
    return None
```

If I'm not mistaken, the behaviour of both functions should be the same, so which one would you recommend?

Thank you in advance! :)

Edit:

Thank you for your quick answers. I understand that this question may be opinion-based.
I was just wondering if there is any PEP recommendation about this or one of the two ways which is seen really more often than the other. Furthermore, about performance, I wanted to know if bytecode generated is the same or not.

Comment: It depends what you want to do.

Comment: I think the first would be easier to debug in the event of problems....and that's why I've voted to close this as "primarily opinion based", because it's obvious that there is no "correct" answer here.

Comment: This might be better suited on the Code Review stack exchange? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could also consider an idiomatic option `{0: 42, 1: 0}.get(param)`.

Comment: Alternately, you could use `return 42 if aParameter == 0 else 1 if aParameter == 1 else None`

Comment: You should read about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), they basically do what you want here without needing a function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's just the three paths, either way is probably fine.  The generally accepted pythonic way when you start having more paths (which would be handled by a switch statement in other languages) is typically with a hash.

```
def myFunction1(aParameter):
    values = {0:42,1:0}
    return values.get(aParameter,None)
```

Comment: Also, `None` is a redundant parameter, because it's by default.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second one because it should be faster, it's cleaner, and easier to read and debug.